# Finder folder icons look like document and image files

Tags: macos, finder, folders, icon

I've got an annoying issue for a couple of weeks now. My folder icons got corrupted from time to time:

[image]

Left side is the view I get when I'm switching between views, but when I open finder or navigate to a folder I see its content as on the right side of the image. When I have multiple files and subfolders in a folder, icons of the folders appear as icons of images, and documents around them...

I have the latest updates and I've never used any app that customises Finder.

Has anybody experienced something similar?

Update: I have Tuxera NTFS 2012.3.4 and OSXfuse 2.5.4 installed. Removing OSXfuse and disabling Tuxera doesn't affect this behaviour.

Update: Same behaviour with OSX 10.8.3

Comment: Which version of OS X do you have?

Comment: Oh, sorry: 10.8.2

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. Can you please add the "mountain-lion" tag to your question then? With that it's clear to everybody what you mean with "latest updates."

Comment: Are those folders stored locally on your harddrive or do you mount them from a network Volume? In the latter case, is it CIFS, AFP, NFS...?

Comment: Locally stored folders and external HDDs.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the Launch Services database. Dig into your **Utilities** folder and paste this into **Terminal**:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

You may need to restart the **Dock** and **Finder** to see if it's worked:

```
killall Dock; killall Finder
```

Alternatively, just reboot after you've reset the Launch Services database.

Comment: Unfortunately resetting the launch service DB and restarting the macbook doesn't help, my icons are still messed up.