# In Finder, folder gets icon when given an extension .md, not with other extensions

Tags: finder

By accident, I see a strange behaviour when creating a folder with an extension `.md`

It gets the the same icon as a file with extension `.md` (the MarkdownLife icon).
For other file extension, I do not see this behaviour.

Is this a bug in Finder? Or markDownLife? Can other confirm this issue?

[image: finder view]

Using:

- OS X Version 10.9.5
- MarkdownLife Version 1.4.0 (20141019)

Comment: It's not a bug: the Finder will try to associate file extensions with custom icon it may have in the cache for that extension.

Comment: Did not see it before: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83910/finder-folder-icons-look-like-document-and-image-files?rq=1